# Any interesting properties of $\sqrt{\sqrt{100x+1}-1}=y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, square-numbers

Are there any interesting properties of: $$\sqrt{\sqrt{100x+1}-1}=y$$
Where $x$ and $y $ are non-negative real intergers.
I'm thinking about what is the digit root? Are there any interesting quirks on divisibility?
Or alternatively (may not be found from previous equation)
$$\sqrt{100x+1}=100a+1$$

Comment: You can write it as $\,100x = y^2(y^2+2)\,$, but it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @dxiv does that mean $100x+1$ isn't a square number?

Comment: Given that say $y\geq10$?

Comment: If $100 x = y^2 (y^2 + 2)$ is to be square then one must find values of $y$ such that $y^2 + 2$ is square. It is evident that if $y$ is an integer then this is not possible to be square and leads to $100 x$ in this manor not being square.

Comment: @leucippus can you prove it?

Comment: @PintOfMilk `does that mean 100x+1 isn't a square number` No, it means no such thing. On the contrary, $\,100x+1=(y^2+1)^2\,$ is always a square. It does, however, mean that $\,100x\,$ is not a square, as pointed out by Leucippus in a previous comment. Seriously, you should make up your mind on what the question is that you want to ask.

Comment: @dxiv I apologise

Comment: @PintOfMilk No need to apologize, but the question still needs to be fixed as to make it answerable at all.

Comment: Though if $x=0$ and $y=0$ then they and $100x$ and $100x+1$ and $y^2+1$ are all squares

Comment: @Henry I should have labelled it as a positive note non-negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon squaring both sides we come up with $$ 100x=y^4 + 2y^2$$

Some integral solutions are found by $y=10k$ and $x= 100k^4+2k^2$ for integer values of $k$.

For example for $k=1$, we get $x=102$ and $y=10$